# What is the English translation of my chop? Is it right side up?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters

I bought calligraphy supplies in a Chinatown and talked with the owner of the store. I told the person (who had her uncle carve this) that I was an artist/painter. I also told her my name in English is Brenda, which comes from Celtic meanings of raven or flaming sword/torch, and that I loved gardening and bamboo.  She took notes and sent it off to her uncle. The finished chop was picked up by someone else, and now years later her store is no longer there. I am hoping someone can tell me what my chop says, and if it is right side up.  Please pardon my ignorance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

百郎妲 /Bǎi láng dá/ is a transliteration of your name Brenda

The meanings of the individual characters in 百郎妲 is irrelevant

*Google transliterates Brenda as 布伦达, which is different from  the one on your chop.*

Comment: It's possible the Chinatown vendor was using more of a Jyutping (Cantonese) sounding than pinyin (Mandarin) sound... Though I speak Cantonese and I have a hard time trying to make it sound like Brenda...

Comment: It is Mandarin pinyin